# sorting filtered data in asp.net listview

Tags: asp.net, listview, sorting

I've created a listview that's filled up with a list of guitars from the database on page load like so:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuitarsLTDBConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guitars", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        lvGuitars.DataSource = dt;
        lvGuitars.DataBind();
    }
```

The following code filters that list of guitars by a certain Make when the user checks the checkbox corresponding to that make

```
protected void chkOrgs_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)lvGuitars.DataSource;
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        if (chkOrgs.SelectedValue == "Gibson")
        {
            dv.RowFilter = "Make = 'Gibson' OR Make='Fender'";
        }
        lvGuitars.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
        lvGuitars.DataBind();
    }
```

Now, what I want to do is be able to sort the latest data that is present within the listview. Meaning, if sort is clicked before filtering, the it should sort all data. If sort is clicked after filtering, it should sort the filtered data. I'm using the following 
code, which is triggered upon a LinkButton click

```
protected void lnkSortResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)lvGuitars.DataSource;
        DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
        dv.Sort = "Make ASC";
        lvGuitars.DataSource = dv.ToTable();
        lvGuitars.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem is that all the data that the listview was loaded with before any filtering is sorted, and not the latest filtered data. How can I change this code so that the latest data available in the listview is the one that's sorted?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GuitarsLTDBConnectionString"].ToString());
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guitars", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    lvGuitars.DataSource = dt;
    lvGuitars.DataBind();
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
}
```

The loading need to be set like this. Access/Update the Viewstate as well on filter and Sorting.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting an 'Object Reference Not Set to an Instance of an Object" error after implementing this code, when I try to filter the data.